# How do I remove this light bulb?

Tags: light-fixture, light, recessed-lighting, bulb, light-bulb

I cannot work out how to remove this type of light bulb in my bathroom. The little black bits on the outside seem to hold it in place, but I can't seem to remove them or the wider unit. And the usual 'push and turn' method on the bulb itself doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Comment: You might want to indicate where these "spikes" are - I can't see any spikes in the picture you've provided. Also, you say "or the wider unit" - is the "wider unit" the trim ring around the fixture?

Comment: Have you tried pulling the entire trim ring straight down?

Comment: Sorry, edited to clarify the 'spikes' are the little black bits around the outside, and the 'wider unit' is indeed the trim ring. Have tried pulling it straight down, but doesn't seem to want to come naturally....bit worried about forcing it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Ymmv, but force it. Maybe use a putty knife for slow leverage.

Comment: You'd have to post a properly exposed photo. I can't see a thing in the darkness.

Comment: (and yes, I get that I’m just some rando on the internet that’s encouraging you to jump off a bridge)

Comment: Look up **MR16 bulb** before you get too convinced that the center part is not one with the reflector part around it. Hard to be 100% certain without a scale reference, but that's what this looks like.